# PHP HTML Resend all GET data with keys on form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, loops, get

How can i add a `foreach()` or a `while()` loop or anything like that in PHP which will
resend all `$_GET` keys and values when submitting a form.
Something like:

```
<?
   echo '<form action="" method="get">';
   echo '<input type="text" name="text_field_1">';
   // LOOP {
      <input type="hidden" name="$row_key" value="$row_value">
   }
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your goal, maybe you can use sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will loop through each `$_GET` key and echo a hidden input with the value

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$value\"/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{$k}\" value=\"{$v}\" />";
}
```

Note if $_GET has not been set this will show an error in newer versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through `$_GET` or you can store the entire `$_GET` array within a session negating the need to do this.

```
if(count($_GET) > 0) {
    foreach($_GET as $var => $val){
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$var\" value=\"$val\"/>";
    }
}
```

or

```
$_SESSION['get'] = $_GET;
```

then you can use `$_SESSION['get']` as if it were `$_GET` later on